# Proving invertibility of a matrix M using the Caley-Hamilton theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

I stumbled upon a question in my textbook saying to use the Cayley-Hamilton theory to deduce that if an $ n \times n $ square matrix $M$ has a non-zero determinant, $M$ is invertible.

I understand how to find the inverse using this theory, but I don't see how you can prove that the inverse exists.

Thanks for any input (:

Comment: Well, finding an inverse should be enough to prove it exists...

Comment: @ArnaudD. I should rephrase: I can find the inverse given a specific n(by basically multiplying both sides of the characteristic polynomial by M^-1) I'd like to know how to generalise this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cayley-Hamilton, $M$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial:

$$ M^n + a_{n - 1}M^{n - 1} + \dots + a_1M + a_0I = 0$$

where $a_0 = (-1)^n\det M$. If $\det M \ne 0$ then you can subtract $a_0I$ from both sides and divide by $a_0$ to get

$$I = -a_0^{-1}M\left( M^{n-1} + a_{n - 1}M^{n - 2} + \dots + a_1 \right).$$

Thus

$$M^{-1} = -a_0^{-1}\left( M^{n-1} + a_{n - 1}M^{n - 2} + \dots + a_1 \right).$$

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask how you deduced that a_0 = (-1)^n det M?

Comment: @Stefanie The characteristic polynomial is $f(x) = \det(xI - M)$. Thus $a_0 = f(0) = \det(-M) = (-1)^n\det(M)$.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $M$ has characteristic polynomial
$$
x^n + a_{n-1}x^n{-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0
$$
with $a_0 \neq 0$.  The formula for our candidate for the inverse is given by
$$
Q = - \frac 1{a_0}(M^{n-1} + a_{n-1}M^{n-2} + \cdots + a_2 M+ a_1 I)
$$
To prove that $Q$ **is** actually the inverse to $M$, it suffices to note that
$$
MQ = M \cdot - \frac 1{a_0}(M^{n-1} + a_{n-1}M^{n-2} + \cdots + a_2 M+ a_1 I) = \\
- \frac 1{a_0}(M^{n} + a_{n-1}M^{n-1} + \cdots + a_2 M^2+ a_1 M) = \\
- \frac 1{a_0}(- a_0 I) = I
$$